# How do i delete the last query ran in mysql

Tags: mysql

When you run a command to count a table after it has done its task, you can hit the up arrow to view the previous commands, etc.

How do I delete it without deleting the entire history. All the research I've done gives me ways to delete the entire history from mysql bash.

Comment: Have you tried to open `~/.mysql_history` with a text editor?

Comment: yes i did, And i deleted a line to test it out and exited mysql and re logged in, the command was still there

Answer (score 0):

That can be usefull ***[Click in my face please](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-clear-mysql-command-history/)***